# node.js - How to upload ReactJS application into the nexus repo

Tags: reactjs, jenkins-pipeline, nexus3

Having the scenario for publishing my ReactJS application into the nexus repository using Jenkins pipeline script.

Anyone having idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In nexus repository, we have repo type called 'raw'. With this resolved my issue.